# Creating a list using HTML or SVG that looks like the attached image

Tags: html, svg

How can I create something like this:

[image]

I don't want to use absolute positioning, I need something that is modular and would be easy to use. I Googled but I have no clue what to search for.

Before down voting, this is just an attempt to see if that's something possible to create using HTML. I really searched but I am clueless

Comment: Did you have a look at [d3.js](http://d3js.org/)?  It might at least be a starting point.

Comment: Thanks. That's a starting point I can check from. To whoever down voted that I hope you feel better now. @ThomasW please post this the link as an answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have time to work it all out, but I figured I could point you the right way.  Disclaimers: I probably have some errors in this - haven't tested it or anything and I've been working in other languages recently.  And this is my first post.

Anyway, I'd use Javascript to make this.  With Jquery, you can even make them move a little.  Make a simple link list in HTML:

```
<ul class="radialLinks">
    <li class="firefox"><a href="Firefox.com">Firefox.com</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link4</a></li>
    <li class="active"><a href="#">Link5</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link6</a></li>
</ul>
```

in CSS, style the links and use image replacement with sprites.  You said no absolute links, but I'd guess your beef with that was relative to the page.  Anyway, I'd do something like this:

```
.radialLinks { position: relative; height: 200px; width: 200px; }
.radialLinks a { position: absolute; height: 24px; width: 24px; text-indent: -9999px; background: transparent url('sprite.png') no-repeat 0 0; }
.radialLinks .active a { background-position: 0 -24px; }
// specific custom overrides
.radialLinks .firefox a { background-position: 0 -48px; }
.radialLinks .active.firefox a { background-position: 0 -72px; }
```

Ideally you'd use something like SASS to more easily create the image replacements and whatnot.  I'd also use Compass for creating the sprites. Then position them with Jquery:

```
$(function() {
        function radialLinks(){
            var radialLinks = $('radialLinks'),
                position = radialLinks.position(),
                size = radialLinks.height();

            var activeChild = radialLinks.find('.active'),
                childSize = activeChild.height(),
                children = radialLinks.find('li:not(.active)'),
                childCount = children.length,
                rotate = 360/childCount,
                rotateIndex = 0,
                radius = height/2 - childHeight/2,
                centerHeight = position.top + size/2,
                centerWidth = position.left + size/2;

            activeChild.position().top = centerHeight - childSize/2;
            activeChild.position().left = centerWidth - childSize/2;

            children.each(function( index ) {
                $this = $(this);
                $this.position().top = centerHeight + (radius * cos(rotate)) - childSize/2;
                $this.position().left = centerWidth + (radius * sin(rotate)) - childSize/2;
                rotateIndex += rotate;
            })

        }
    });
```

I'm out of time, so I've got to punt with the lines, but I hope this helps.

Comment: No prob.  Hope it helps.  If I get a chance, I'll flush it out a bit more for ya.